# iFrame Not Working with Mobile Version of Website

Tags: javascript, mobile, iframe

So I have a site that uses iFrames for a similar purpose as StumbleUpon and the site works (or is supposed to work) on mobile as well as desktop. I run into an issue on mobile when the iFrame contains content from Yahoo! News. This content works both on desktop and iPad but when it comes to use on iPhone the frame shows nothing.

I believe the issue is caused by Yahoo! News switching to its mobile version which somehow messes up the iFrame. So I need help! I've tried disabling JavaScript using the sandbox parameter, that doesn't seem to do the trick, and I've tried a bunch of tricks to try and keep it on the desktop version of the site but that doesn't seem to work either.

I'm fine with it either staying on the desktop version or switching to the mobile, I just want it to be viewable. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Well in your case the problem is caused by Iframe loading the mobile version of the yahoo site. For Yahoo you can force the desktop version by adding passing parameter m=1 to the url like this: http://www.yahoo.com/?m=1 . So for your iframe source try adding that in, see if that works

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work for news.yahoo.com.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile can be tracked from php too so i don't think javascript will work.

You can find search deeper the yahoo url, maybe you find a url that dont change to mobile version

or

load the page code on your sever and then display it inside the iframe (or open inside the iframe a page in your server that do this) but i dont think you should do it...